# Python removing delimiters from strings

Tags: python

I have 2 related questions/ issues.

```
def remove_delimiters (delimiters, s):
    for d in delimiters:
        ind = s.find(d)
        while ind != -1:
            s = s[:ind] + s[ind+1:]
            ind = s.find(d)

    return ' '.join(s.split())


delimiters = [",", ".", "!", "?", "/", "&", "-", ":", ";", "@", "'", "..."]
d_dataset_list = ['hey-you...are you ok?']
d_list = []

for d in d_dataset_list:
    d_list.append(remove_delimiters(delimiters, d[1]))

print d_list
```

Output = `'heyyouare you ok'`

1. What is the best way of avoiding strings being combined together when a delimiter is removed?  For example, so that the output is `hey you are you ok` ?
2. There may be a number of different sequences of `...`, for example `..` or `..........` etc.  How does one go around implementing some form of rule, where if more than one `.` appear after each other, to remove it?  I want to try and avoid hard-coding all sequences in my delimiters list.  Thankyou

Comment: You have a single dot in your delimiter list, but then you ask us how to remove two or more dots. Which is it, should single dots stay or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like this:

1. Given delimiters `d`, join them to a regular expression

   ```
   >>> d = ",.!?/&-:;@'..."
   >>> "["+"\\".join(d)+"]"
   "[,\\.\\!\\?\\/\\&\\-\\:\\;\\@\\'\\.\\.\\.]"
   ```
2. Split the string using this regex with `re.split`

   ```
   >>> s = 'hey-you...are you ok?'
   >>> re.split("["+"\\".join(d)+"]", s)
   ['hey', 'you', '', '', 'are you ok', '']
   ```
3. Join all the non-empty fragments back together

   ```
   >>> ' '.join(w for w in re.split("["+"\\".join(d)+"]", s) if w)
   'hey you are you ok'
   ```

Also, if you just want to remove all non-word characters, you can just use the character group `\W` instead of manually enumerating all the delimiters:

```
>>> ' '.join(w for w in re.split(r"\W", s) if w)
'hey you are you ok'
```

Answer (score 1):

So first of all, your function for removing delimiters could be simplified greatly by using the replace function (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm)

This would help solve your first question. Instead of just removing them, replace with a space, then get rid of the spaces using the pattern you already used (split() treats consecutive delimiters as one)

A better function, which does this, would be:

```
def remove_delimiters (delimiters, s):
    new_s = s
    for i in delimiters: #replace each delimiter in turn with a space
        new_s = new_s.replace(i, ' ')
    return ' '.join(new_s.split())
```

to answer your second question, I'd say it's time for regular expressions

```
>>> import re
... ss = 'hey ... you are ....... what?'
... print re.sub('[.+]',' ',ss)
hey     you are         what?
>>>
```