# Is there a function that removes delimiters from list composed of strings and other lists?

Tags: python

I have a row that looks like this:

```
Alain,David,43,"['Cinema:ABC', 'Cafe:Evasion', 'Hotel:Hotel Du Parc', 'Cafe:Casa del gelato']","['Notebook', 'Cigarette électronique', 'Livre:Roman']","['Matin:8h-10h', 'Apres-midi:12h-15h']","['Politique']
```

I have tried to remove delimiters ([,],"",'') to obtain something like this in order to calculate similarity between rows later:

```
Alain,David,43,Cinema:ABC, Cafe:Evasion, Hotel:Hotel Du Parc, Cafe:Casa del gelato,Notebook, Cigarette électronique, Livre:Roman,Matin:8h-10h, Apres-midi:12h-15h,Politique
```

But it failed! 
Any idea?

Comment: What did you try, and how exactly did it fail?

Comment: Tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221535/python-removing-delimiters-from-strings

Comment: I tried this function:                                                                                                                        def remover(lists):
    delimiter = ["[","]"]
    for i in range(len(lists)):
        for j in delimiter:
            if (lists[i]==j):
                lists[i]==""
    return lists

Comment: @DaminiGanesh yess i checked it .. it doesn't help . In fact i'm using a list of lists and it won't read what inside the sublists ..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It will be better if you can put what you tried in the body of the question, not a comment. Show the output of what you tried and why it doesn't work. Also, if your actual data contains a list of lists then show that in example in the question, as it will require a different solution.

Comment: Your input row does not look like valid python? Also, what is a "row" is it a row in pandas? a list? a single string?
Similarly for your output, what data format is that? currently it's not anything in python

Comment: you have string `[...]` - if you even remove `[`, `]` then you still have one column with one string, not many columns. You would have to covert string to list and create new columns.

Comment: @TheLaurens in fact i generated a cvs file with theses fiels ['Prenom','Nom','Age','Lieux frequentés','Habitudes d achat','Horaire des activités','Centres d interet'] (sorry it is in french !) then i tried to calculate the similarity of each row of the csv file with the other rows and ofc this requires to have the same type of data (strings) In short I'm trying to remove all these delimiters ...

Comment: did you generate this CSV ? then change code which generates this CSV and you will not have to remove delimiters. There are not delimiters in CSV but chars in strings. If you remove these chars you still have one string and it will not make it correct CSV.

Comment: @furas that's how i generated the file from lists that contains given expressions 
 file.writerow([random.choice(Prenoms),random.choice(Noms),random.randint(17,65),random.sample(Lfreq,4)])

Comment: you should write `random.sample(Lfreq,4)` as separated elements,

Comment: see example with `random.sample(Lfreq,4)` in answer below

Comment: @furas converting strings to lists was much better! thank you for the help i appreciate it

Comment: it is better to create correct CSV at start - one day you may need this CSV in different program which can't convert strings to lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have list, not string

```
 row = ['Alain','David',43,"['Cinema:ABC', 'Cafe:Evasion', 'Hotel:Hotel Du Parc', 'Cafe:Casa del gelato']","['Notebook', 'Cigarette électronique', 'Livre:Roman']","['Matin:8h-10h', 'Apres-midi:12h-15h']","['Politique']"]
```

You have string with list in some columns. You have to convert back string to list. You can use `eval()` to convert string to Python's list.

```
result = []

for item in row:
    if isinstance(item, str) and item.startswith('['):
        result += eval(item)
    else:
        result.append(item)

print(result)
```

---

**EDIT:**

You generate it with

```
file.writerow([
   random.choice(Prenoms),
   random.choice(Noms),
   random.randint(17,65),
   random.sample(Lfreq,4)
])
```

But `random.sample(Lfreq,4)` gives list which you have to write as separated columns.

```
data = random.sample(Lfreq,4)

file.writerow([
    random.choice(Prenoms), 
    random.choice(Noms),
    random.randint(17,65), 
    data[0], 
    data[1], 
    data[2], 
    data[3]
])
```

or extend list using `extend` or `+=`

```
data = [random.choice(Prenoms), random.choice(Noms), random.randint(17,65)]

#data.extend(random.sample(Lfreq,4))
data += random.sample(Lfreq,4)

file.writerow(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function that solves this.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

def plain_array_from_array_with_subarrays_as_strings(array):
    response = []
    for el in array:
        if not isinstance(el, (int, float)):
            sub_els = re.findall(r"'([^']+)'", el)
            if len(sub_els) > 0:
                for sub_el in sub_els:
                    response.append(sub_el)
            else:
                response.append(el)
        else:
            response.append(el)
    return response

r = [
    "Alain",
    "David",
    43,
    "['Cinema:ABC', 'Cafe:Evasion', 'Hotel:Hotel Du Parc', 'Cafe:Casa del gelato']",
    "['Notebook', 'Cigarette électronique', 'Livre:Roman']",
    "['Matin:8h-10h', 'Apres-midi:12h-15h']",
    "['Politique']"
]    
print(plain_array_from_array_with_subarrays_as_strings(r))
```

Output:

```
['Alain',
 'David',
 43,
 'Cinema:ABC',
 'Cafe:Evasion',
 'Hotel:Hotel Du Parc',
 'Cafe:Casa del gelato',
 'Notebook',
 'Cigarette électronique',
 'Livre:Roman',
 'Matin:8h-10h',
 'Apres-midi:12h-15h',
 'Politique']
```